# Embedding a graph into a GUI (Qtdesigner and Pyside)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside, qt-designer, pyqtgraph

I am new to stack overflow. This is my first post so please do correct me out if I am wrong. Will be precise and explain my issue.

I have a sensor which records, yaw and pitch and the recorded data has been processed and clipped according to the project requirements. I want to embed the graph which is being generated in the GUI. I am using Qt designer and Pyside to do this.

I did read up on pyqtgraph documentation and went through the examples,documentation and didn't get a good grasp of it.However I followed the steps,

*"In Designer, create a QGraphicsView widget (“Graphics View” under the “Display Widgets” category).
Right-click on the QGraphicsView and select “Promote To...”.
Under “Promoted class name”, enter the class name you wish to use (“PlotWidget”, “GraphicsLayoutWidget”, etc).
Under “Header file”, enter “pyqtgraph”.
Click “Add”, then click “Promote”."*

Now how to address the graphics view widget and pyqtgraph to plot a graph within the gui?

Here is my QtDsigner code:

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'hts.ui'
#
# Created: Tue May 16 16:32:58 2017
#      by: pyside-uic 0.2.15 running on PySide 1.2.2
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class Ui_HTS(object):
    def setupUi(self, HTS):
        HTS.setObjectName("HTS")
        HTS.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.NonModal)
        HTS.resize(1282, 628)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        HTS.setFont(font)
        HTS.setTabShape(QtGui.QTabWidget.Rounded)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(HTS)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.load_file = QtGui.QToolButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.load_file.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1010, 50, 111, 51))
        self.load_file.setObjectName("load_file")
        self.time_clipping_chk_box = QtGui.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.time_clipping_chk_box.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1010, 210, 231, 31))
        self.time_clipping_chk_box.setObjectName("time_clipping_chk_box")
        self.start_time = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.start_time.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1090, 259, 113, 22))
        self.start_time.setObjectName("start_time")
        self.label_2 = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1000, 260, 91, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.stop_time = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.stop_time.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1090, 299, 113, 22))
        self.stop_time.setObjectName("stop_time")
        self.label_3 = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1000, 300, 91, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.continuous_loop = QtGui.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.continuous_loop.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1140, 60, 131, 20))
        self.continuous_loop.setObjectName("continuous_loop")
        self.pitch_check_box = QtGui.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.pitch_check_box.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1014, 120, 81, 20))
        self.pitch_check_box.setObjectName("pitch_check_box")
        self.yaw_check_box = QtGui.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.yaw_check_box.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1130, 120, 81, 20))
        self.yaw_check_box.setObjectName("yaw_check_box")
        self.graphicsView = PlotWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.graphicsView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 961, 561))
        self.graphicsView.setObjectName("graphicsView")
        HTS.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(HTS)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1282, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        HTS.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(HTS)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        HTS.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(HTS)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(HTS)

    def retranslateUi(self, HTS):
        HTS.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("HTS", "Hand Tremor Simulator", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.load_file.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("HTS", "Load File", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.time_clipping_chk_box.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("HTS", "Time Clipping(secs)", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.start_time.setPlaceholderText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("HTS", "sec", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.label_2.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("HTS", "Start Time:", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.stop_time.setPlaceholderText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("HTS", "sec", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.label_3.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("HTS", "Stop Time:", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.continuous_loop.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("HTS", "Continuous", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pitch_check_box.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("HTS", "Pitch", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.yaw_check_box.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("HTS", "Yaw", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))

from pyqtgraph import PlotWidget
```

This is the Pyside code I am trying to run and to plot the generated graph inside the gui.

```
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtCore import *
import sys
# import hts_signal_proc
import htsgui
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pyqtgraph as pg


class HTS(QMainWindow,htsgui.Ui_HTS):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(HTS, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.connect(self.load_file,SIGNAL('clicked()'),self.original_waveform)

    def original_waveform(self):
        # selected_directory_csv, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open File', '',
        #                                                              'csv Files (*.csv)', None,
        #                                                              QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog)
        # print(selected_directory_csv)
        # if selected_directory_csv != '':
        #     pitch,yaw,time = hts_signal_proc.load_csv_file(selected_directory_csv)
        pitch = [0.79, 0.5, 0.33, 0.28, 0.35, 0.53, 0.84, 1.23, 1.53, 1.71, 1.73, 1.62, 1.42, 1.17, 0.93, 0.75, 0.58, 0.47, 0.41, 0.4, 0.42, 0.46, 0.5, 0.52, 0.51, 0.46, 0.33, 0.19, -0.05, -0.29, -0.5, -0.58, -0.51, -0.25, 0.07, 0.33, 0.51, 0.54, 0.39, 0.01, -0.43, -0.72, -0.82, -0.88, -0.81, -0.61, -0.52, -0.78, -1.09, -1.36, -1.65, -1.81, -1.84, -1.77, -1.63, -1.53, -1.47, -1.46, -1.5, -1.59, -1.7, -1.76, -1.69, -1.48, -1.27, -1.21, -1.36, -1.78, -2.42, -3.02, -3.45, -3.6, -3.45, -3.11, -2.76, -2.4, -2.0, -1.62, -1.25, -0.99, -1.02, -1.24, -1.57, -1.96, -2.32, -2.6, -2.8, -3.08, -3.24, -3.27, -2.91, -2.44, -1.86, -1.17, -0.39, 0.3, 0.82, 1.17, 1.28, 1.12, 0.76, 0.31, -0.12, -0.61, -1.08, -1.37, -1.49, -1.58, -1.59, -1.5, -1.41, -1.38, -1.5, -1.74, -2.0, -2.19, -2.34, -2.43, -2.5, -2.57, -2.68, -2.86, -3.08, -3.25, -3.27, -3.1, -2.81, -2.48, -2.14, -1.85, -1.68, -1.69, -1.76, -1.82, -1.88, -1.9, -1.86, -1.72, -1.58, -1.47, -1.35, -1.19, -1.03, -0.93, -0.83, -0.82, -0.84, -0.99, -1.23, -1.49, -1.68, -1.76, -1.72, -1.45, -0.96, -0.19, 0.73, 1.71, 2.46, 3.14, 3.74, 4.21, 4.43, 4.48, 4.37, 4.09, 3.74, 3.34, 2.84, 2.29, 1.91, 1.67, 1.41, 1.11, 0.82, 0.55, 0.28, -0.04, -0.47, -0.83, -1.05, -1.28, -1.59, -1.97, -2.35, -2.71, -3.0, -3.16, -3.31, -3.53, -3.77, -3.89, -4.0, -4.04, -4.02, -4.15, -4.52, -4.99, -5.34, -5.49, -5.54, -5.49, -5.34, -5.06, -4.73, -4.35, -3.99, -3.77, -3.79, -4.03, -4.48, -5.04, -5.66, -6.25, -6.7, -6.9, -6.84, -6.58, -6.2, -5.71, -5.12, -4.45, -3.64, -2.85, -2.31, -2.08, -2.16, -2.54, -3.23, -4.19, -5.34, -6.56, -7.46, -8.08, -8.56, -9.0, -9.34, -9.5, -9.39, -8.95, -8.27, -7.43, -6.66, -6.27, -6.21, -6.21, -6.26, -6.19, -5.93, -5.45, -4.79, -4.03, -3.26, -2.52, -1.84, -1.34, -1.14, -1.28, -1.61, -1.97, -2.39, -2.93, -3.48, -3.88, -4.04, -3.92, -3.5, -2.89, -2.32, -1.92, -1.77, -1.83, -2.01, -2.23, -2.35, -2.5, -2.7, -2.88, -3.14, -3.4, -3.48, -3.29, -2.92, -2.38, -1.6, -0.76, -0.08, 0.48, 0.93, 1.17, 1.21, 0.93, 0.49, -0.13, -0.93, -1.75, -2.62, -3.43, -3.99, -4.18, -4.14, -3.85, -3.43, -2.99, -2.47, -1.84, -1.29, -0.92, -0.86, -1.02, -1.3, -1.71, -2.31, -3.02, -3.74, -4.39, -4.78, -4.9, -4.87, -4.71, -4.55, -4.45, -4.38, -4.3, -4.13, -4.0, -3.92, -3.76, -3.81, -4.03, -4.34, -4.69, -4.98, -5.2, -5.21, -5.05, -4.78, -4.42, -4.05, -3.75, -3.5, -3.34, -3.31, -3.37, -3.51, -3.68, -3.98, -4.32, -4.7, -5.18, -5.71, -6.2, -6.68, -6.87, -6.82, -6.58, -6.25, -5.88, -5.59, -5.52, -5.69, -6.05, -6.52, -6.95, -7.39, -7.86, -8.21, -8.57, -8.97, -9.26, -9.34, -9.29, -9.01, -8.62, -8.19, -7.76, -7.35, -6.87, -6.48, -6.31, -6.36, -6.7, -7.3, -8.06, -8.96, -9.83, -10.61, -11.2, -11.64, -12.03, -12.41, -12.75, -12.82, -12.6, -12.17, -11.62, -10.91, -10.17, -9.69, -9.32, -9.1, -9.03, -9.18, -9.44, -9.73, -9.98, -10.12, -9.91, -9.27, -8.41, -7.59, -6.86, -6.22, -5.89, -5.85, -6.07, -6.52, -7.13, -7.75, -8.22, -8.49, -8.56, -8.42, -8.08, -7.64, -7.03, -6.33, -5.68, -5.07, -4.54, -4.22, -4.13, -4.32, -4.74, -5.3, -5.87, -6.43, -6.9, -7.39, -7.92, -8.28, -8.46, -8.38, -8.0, -7.43, -6.78, -6.01, -5.1, -4.17, -3.51, -3.08, -3.0, -3.27, -3.71, -4.33, -5.09, -5.94, -6.71, -7.34, -7.82, -8.02, -7.83, -7.38, -6.77, -6.06, -5.33, -4.58, -4.0, -3.65, -3.47, -3.53, -3.88, -4.47, -5.3, -6.28, -7.29, -8.19, -8.85, -9.12, -9.09, -8.8, -8.25, -7.58, -6.83, -6.09, -5.49, -5.21, -5.25, -5.62, -6.28, -7.13, -7.98, -8.84, -9.53, -10.06, -10.34, -10.38, -10.3, -10.08, -9.73, -9.24, -8.61, -7.99, -7.49, -7.12, -6.86, -6.72, -6.72, -6.86, -7.11, -7.43, -7.75, -8.0, -8.14, -8.05, -7.8, -7.49, -7.1, -6.69, -6.27, -5.9, -5.66, -5.53, -5.52, -5.62, -5.85, -6.13, -6.28, -6.32, -6.26, -6.14, -6.01, -5.83, -5.56, -5.26, -4.91, -4.51, -4.11, -3.74, -3.37, -3.05, -2.89, -2.98, -3.23, -3.63, -4.1, -4.52, -4.89, -5.15, -5.25, -5.12, -4.81, -4.47, -4.14, -3.95, -3.88, -3.71, -3.47, -3.35, -3.32, -3.53, -3.94, -4.51, -5.2, -5.82, -6.35, -6.68, -6.84, -6.88, -6.64, -6.32, -6.01, -5.72, -5.42, -5.24, -5.22, -5.34, -5.64, -6.07, -6.75, -7.57, -8.27, -9.0, -9.7, -10.21, -10.37, -10.26, -9.93, -9.45, -8.94, -8.43, -7.99, -7.63, -7.4, -7.35, -7.61, -8.03, -8.58, -9.24, -9.92, -10.3, -10.49, -10.55, -10.27, -9.83, -9.18, -8.34, -7.45, -6.62, -5.92, -5.34, -4.9, -4.66, -4.55, -4.64, -4.97, -5.54, -6.25, -6.87, -7.31, -7.46, -7.38, -7.14, -6.79, -6.38, -5.94, -5.43, -4.96, -4.59, -4.36, -4.25, -4.37, -4.71, -5.26, -6.06, -6.95, -7.83, -8.75, -9.68, -10.42, -10.88, -11.1, -11.08, -10.87, -10.43, -9.81, -9.15, -8.4, -7.69, -7.16, -6.89, -6.86, -7.08, -7.56, -8.33, -9.31, -10.33, -11.22, -11.78, -11.92, -11.8, -11.41, -10.8, -10.08, -9.18, -8.28, -7.48, -6.91, -6.6, -6.48, -6.63, -7.0, -7.55, -8.13, -8.54, -8.67, -8.66, -8.54, -8.38, -8.16, -7.95, -7.73, -7.52, -7.19, -6.77, -6.33, -5.96, -5.68, -5.52, -5.35, -5.17, -5.0, -4.87, -4.83, -4.89, -4.99, -5.1, -5.27, -5.45, -5.57, -5.65, -5.7, -5.72, -5.81, -5.99, -6.25, -6.54, -6.76, -6.75, -6.46, -6.02, -5.54, -4.98, -4.44, -4.0, -3.65, -3.52, -3.57, -3.69, -3.78, -3.79, -3.73, -3.61, -3.35, -3.0, -2.63, -2.34, -1.99, -1.59, -1.23, -0.98, -0.92, -1.01, -1.15, -1.29, -1.43, -1.57, -1.84, -2.19, -2.64, -3.07, -3.37, -3.49, -3.4, -3.2, -2.99, -2.8, -2.62, -2.49, -2.44, -2.55, -2.88, -3.4, -4.02, -4.69, -5.25, -5.74, -6.2, -6.49, -6.61, -6.57, -6.29, -5.96, -5.65, -5.36, -5.14, -4.99, -5.04, -5.27, -5.64, -6.07, -6.46, -6.88, -7.22, -7.43, -7.53, -7.39, -7.09, -6.62, -6.04, -5.47, -4.8, -4.17, -3.82, -3.75, -4.0, -4.5, -5.11, -5.79, -6.39, -7.0, -7.17, -7.0, -6.73, -6.33, -5.85, -5.27, -4.69, -4.25, -4.0, -3.94, -3.87, -3.87, -3.95, -4.03, -4.08, -4.12, -4.12, -4.18, -4.18, -4.22, -4.23, -4.18, -4.15, -4.03, -3.82, -3.61, -3.46, -3.36, -3.22, -3.0, -2.75, -2.64, -2.6, -2.56, -2.48, -2.21, -1.69, -0.91, 0.11, 1.11, 1.79, 2.13, 2.13, 1.93, 1.65, 1.45, 1.33, 1.23, 1.07, 0.89, 0.62, 0.27, -0.07, -0.32, -0.51, -0.68, -0.88, -1.12, -1.33, -1.32, -1.13, -0.9, -0.8, -0.94, -1.26, -1.65, -1.98, -2.22, -2.35, -2.49, -2.76, -3.1, -3.44, -3.69, -3.74, -3.55, -3.23, -2.86, -2.51, -2.16, -1.73, -1.26, -0.8, -0.39, -0.12, -0.07, -0.1, -0.18, -0.28, -0.35, -0.39, -0.42, -0.41, -0.4, -0.25, 0.05, 0.28, 0.42, 0.53, 0.57, 0.59, 0.67, 0.89, 1.21, 1.44, 1.53, 1.48]

        pw = pg.PlotWidget()
        self.graphicsView.pw.plot(pitch) #This is not working

        # else:
        #     print('No selected file')           


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = HTS()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You no longer have to create a PlotWidget object since graphicsView is, you just have to change:

```
pw = pg.PlotWidget()
self.graphicsView.pw.plot(pitch) #This is not working
```

to:

```
self.graphicsView.plot(pitch) #This is working
```

[image]